# Is the Do insertion missing in this headline?

Tags: do-support

> What Democrats really think about presidential tax returns

or

> What do Democrats really think about presidential tax returns

Comment: Headlines routinely omit words -- but in this case if you add "do" it becomes a question, right? The first sentence is a statement.

Comment: yes, but if we look for an ellipsis of auxiliary verb then can we say there is the ellipsis of do auxiliary verb?

Comment: If you look for missing things, you could find a missing initial phrase, "Here is", or you could find the missing word "do" plus a missing question mark. The question mark is very important to indicate a question and would not have been left out.

Answer (score 4):

As these are written rather than spoken; adding the "do" will change how most people understand the phrase.

The first instance reads as a statement of fact:

> [Here is] what democrats really think about presidential tax returns

The most likely way people will parse the second instance, is as a rhetorical question:

> What do democrats really think about presidential tax returns[?]

Answer (score 1):

It is not - in this instance, the headline is saying "[This article is about] what Democrats really think about presidential tax returns".